# Calculate $\iint_D xy\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

> Calculate $$\iint_D xy\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy$$
> where $D$ is the region bounded by $y = x^2$, $2y = x^2$, $x^2 = y$ and $x^2 = 2y$.

---

Can I do it as follows:
$$\iint_D xy\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy = \int_{y^2}^{y^2/2}\mathrm dx \int_{x^2}^{x^2/2} xy~ \mathrm dy = \int_{y^2}^{y^2/2}x\left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_{x^2}^{x^2/2}\mathrm dx = \int_{y^2}^{y^2/2}\left(\frac{-3x^5}{8}\right)\mathrm dx$$
However, the integral is going to be a function of $y$. I think I'm wrong with this. Or should I divide this region into $4$ regions with four vertical lines passing through the points of intersections?

---

[image]

Comment: I would split it in three regions. As an example consider $x\in[1,1,26]$. The black and red lines are Lower and upper bounds for $y$ for each value of $x$, respectively. So you integrate first with respect to $y$ over those limits and then with respect to $x$ over $[1,1.26]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each step of calculating a multivariate integral, you should not have the variables, with respect to which the integral has been simplified, still present. This occurrence is typically due to wrong choice of the integration region. To correctly express the domain,

- write down all the constraints
  $$
  {x^2/2<y<x^2
  \\
  y^2/2<x<y^2.
  }
  $$
- Choose the order of integration. I choose integration first w.r.t. $x$ and then $y$.
- Derive the bound of $x$ variation in terms of $y$ from the constraints of the integration region,
  $$
  {
  y^2/2<x<y^2
  \\
  \sqrt y<x<\sqrt {2y}
  }\implies
  {
  \max\{y^2/2,\sqrt y\}<x<\min\{y^2,\sqrt{2y}\}
  }.
  $$
- Find the maximal numerical interval of $y$ variation. This process is simple and gives $(1,2)$ here.
- Express the integral in its alternative form as
  $$
  \int_1^2\int_{\max\{y^2/2,\sqrt y\}}^{\min\{y^2,\sqrt{2y}\}}xydxdy
  .
  $$

All done!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it instead...

Answer (score 1):

By making a change of variables:
$$
u=\frac{y}{x^2},\qquad v=\frac{x}{y^2}
$$
we have that the conditions that define the domain simplify to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\leq u\leq 1,\qquad\frac{1}{2}\leq v\leq 1
$$
Let's see that from the transformation rules we have $uv=1/(xy)$ then
$$
J^{-1}=\left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|=\frac{3}{x^2y^2}
$$
and
$$
J=\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|=\frac{1}{3u^2v^2}
$$
so that
$$
\int_Dxydxdy=\int_{D'}\frac{1}{uv}\cdot\frac{1}{3u^2v^2}dudv=\frac{1}{3}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{du}{u^3}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{dv}{v^3}=\frac{3}{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there a general way to think of any of such a change of variables?

Comment: @NodeJS: no, not really, but this is a typical case, because two delimiting curves are of type $y=kx^2$ and the other two are of type $x=ky^2$, so it is easy to see that in the former case $y/x^2$ is constant on both curves and in the latter $x/y^2$ is constant

Comment: Thank you. This helps!